# Synonym request: "gtalk" to "google-talk"

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request, retag-request

The one is obviously a short-hand way of saying the other.

[gtalk](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gtalk) should be made a synonym of [google-talk](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-talk) and merged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done.